# Column transformer corrupts column

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, scikit-learn, pipeline

I tried this code in order to impute missing values on my column (any strategy)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

X=pd.dataframe('namefile.csv')

li=['feature1']

# X['feature1'].Value_Counts of feature1:
# 0.00  7269
# 1.00  1745
# nan   683
# 2.00  607
# 3.00  520
# 4.00  146
# 5.00  31
# 6.00  6

p=ColumnTransformer(remainder='passthrough',transformers=[('simp',SimpleImputer(),li)])
z=p.fit_transform(X)
DF_Z=pd.DataFrame(z,X.columns)


#Distrbution Checking
# DF_Z['feature1'].Value_Counts of feature1:
# 4.00  7269
# 3.00  3137
# 5.00   2170
# 2.00  403
# 0.00  235
# 1.00  45
```

I don't understand why the transformer corrupts the completion of values. And I do not understand why values ​​that were not missing were changed.

Comment: Indeed, it shouldn't behave as such; therefore, I would say your issue is not completely reproducible (unless I'm overlooking at something). Would you mind adding some specification on your data?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the data is correct, but the column order has changed, and so your re-framing it has put the wrong column labels on.  Try

```py
DF_Z = pd.DataFrame(z, p.get_feature_names_out())
```